# How to sort encrypted data by PHP in Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, eloquent

I have store information in MySQL table with PHP (Laravel) encrypted string, now how I can sort it using MySQL query in Laravel.

ex. The first name is store in the database with PHP encrypted string now I do sorting the first name from the database when getting the number of records.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a free coding service. You are expected to make your best attempt at solving the problem, and then sharing your code so that we may help you. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69431125/edit) to include your code. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the encryption algorithm present for MySQL implementation as well? If yes, then you can _also_ decrypt and sort before getting from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**eloquent's accessor**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) feature.

Example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily sort using [**collection's sorting**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby).

Example:

```php
User::all()->sortBy('first_name');
```